# Awk string replacement

Tags: string, bash, awk

I need to split a csv string into an array, and cut the content of its elements to a lngth or 300 if the element's content exceed the 300 characters.
I'm very close to it but for some reason that i cant figure out, this is not working:

```
awk '{split($0,fields,",") 
 for(field in fields)
    if(length(fields[field]) >300){
     gsub(fields[field],substr(fields[field],0,300),$0)
   } print 
 }' file_in.csv > file_out
```

I can see it when i run this test:

```
awk '{split($0,fields,","); for(field in fields) if(length(fields[field]) >=301){print fields[field]} }' file_out
```

This is still prnting some fields
Any idea whats wrong with my awk?

Comment: It would help both you and us if you didn't use an inline script for this. It's not trivial enough. I'd save it to a file, put some newlines into it, and come back

Comment: Avoid to use `gsub` in such a case, because characters `?` and `\` are interpreted as special characters (resp. wildcard and escape next one). Instead call only `substr`.

Comment: @Bentoy13 you mean sub() , not substr()

Comment: @JBoy Not really, you don't need to call `gsub` or `sub`... `substr` is enough to get the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk to trim fields > 300:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
     {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (length($i)>300) $i=substr($i,1,300)}
     1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed 300 by 3 to do it readable:

```
$echo "Hello,World"| awk '{split($0, fields,",");str=""; for (field in fields){str = str substr(fields[field],0,3) ","}; print substr(str,0,length(str)-1)}'
Hel,wor
```

Line is a little long, splitted is:

```
awk '{split($0, fields,",");
      str="";
      for (field in fields){
         str = str substr(fields[field],0,3) ","
      };
      print substr(str,0,length(str)-1)}'
```